# How to inject Styled Components to React iframe

Tags: reactjs, iframe, styled-components, react-frame-component

I'm building a chrome extension and I need to do style isolation using iframe, specifically 'react-frame-component' and I'm using styled-components for styles but the generated classes are not injected in the iframe, any ideas on how can I inject them to the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

It's not made explicit in the styled-components documentation and probably isn't a supported use-case, but you can wrap your components in a [StyleSheetManager](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#stylesheetmanager) and pass it a `target` prop with the DOM node (*not* a React ref) to tell it where to inject its styles; so you'd ideally pass it the `head` element from the iframe's content.

I'm not familiar with `react-frame-component` so I'm not sure how you might access the iframe `head`

EDIT: This question is better answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66557426/11643

Answer (score -1):

You can achive this with normal `<iframe/>` tag.

```
const iFrame = useRef(null);

const applyStyle =  (ele: Document) => {
    const styleTag = document.createElement("link");
    styleTag.type = "text/css";
    styleTag.rel = "stylesheet";
    styleTag.href = "../styles.css";
    ele.head.appendChild(styleTag);
}

const onLoad = () => {
    applyStyle(iFrame.current.contentDocument);
}  

return (
   <iframe 
      id="doc-iframe"
      frameBorder="0"
      scrolling={"yes"} 
      src={url} 
      ref={iframeRef}
  />
);
```

Comment: Your suggestion ignores the `styled-components` part of the question and just adds a link to a `styles.css` that doesn't exist for the OP.