# Styled components are not rendering in React Iframe?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, iframe, styled-components

1. List item

I've created a React Iframe (using 'react-frame-component'), and some styled components. When I try to render the styled components inside the React Iframe, the styled components inherits the Parent's (App.css) style, and loses its unique style. Is it possible to maintain the styled component?

Here is my code:

Content.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Frame, { FrameContextConsumer } from 'react-frame-component';
import App from "./App";
class Main extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Frame head={[<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href={chrome.runtime.getURL("/static/css/content.css")} ></link>]}>
               <FrameContextConsumer>
               {
                  ({document, window}) => {
                    return <App document={document} window={window} isExt={true}/>
                  }
                }
                </FrameContextConsumer>
            </Frame>

        )
    }
}
```

App.js

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Card from './components/Card/index';



class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
      <div className="App">
          {this.props.isExt ?
            <img src={chrome.runtime.getURL("static/media/logo.svg")} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          :
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          }
          <Card />
      </div>


      </>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Style:

```js
import React from "react";
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";

export const CardWrapper = styled.div`
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 0 32px;
  margin: 48px auto 0;
  width: 300px;
  font-family: Quicksand, arial, sans-serif;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 0px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  border-radius: 5px;
`;

export const CardHeader = styled.header`
  padding-top: 32px;
  padding-bottom: 32px;
`;

export const CardHeading = styled.h1`
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
`;

export const CardBody = styled.div`
  padding-right: 32px;
  padding-left: 32px;
`;

export const CardFieldset = styled.fieldset`
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;

  & + & {
    margin-top: 24px;
  }

  &:nth-last-of-type(2) {
    margin-top: 32px;
  }

  &:last-of-type {
    text-align: center;
  }
`;

export const CardInput = styled.input`
  padding: 7px 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-top: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-left: 0;
  transition: border-bottom-color 0.25s ease-in;

  &:focus {
    border-bottom-color: #e5195f;
    outline: 0;
  }
`;

export const CardIcon = styled.span`
  color: #666;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: .25;
  transition: opacity .25s ease-in;

  &:hover {
    opacity: .95;
  }

  ${props =>
    props.big &&
    css`
      font-size: 26px;
    `}

  ${props =>
    props.eye &&
    css`
      position: absolute;
      top: 8px;
      right: 0;
    `}

  ${props =>
    props.small &&
    css`
      font-size: 14px;
    `}
`;

export const CardOptionsNote = styled.small`
  padding-top: 8px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
`;

export const CardOptions = styled.ul`
  padding: 0;
  margin: 16px 0 8px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
`;

export const CardOptionsItem = styled.li`
  &:nth-of-type(n + 2) {
    margin-left: 16px;
  }
`;

export const CardButton = styled.button`
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 0;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #e5195f;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 35px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.02, 0.01, 0.47, 1);

  &:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 15px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
    transform: translate(0, -5px);
  }
`;

export const CardLink = styled.a`
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #aaa;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: color 0.25s ease-in;

  &:hover {
    color: #777;
  }
`;
```

Component:

```js
import React from "react";

import {
  CardWrapper,
  CardHeader,
  CardHeading,
  CardBody,
  CardIcon,
  CardFieldset,
  CardInput,
  CardOptionsItem,
  CardOptions,
  CardOptionsNote,
  CardButton,
  CardLink
} from './Card';


const Card = () => {
    return (
    <>
      <CardWrapper>
        <CardHeader>
          <CardHeading>Sign in</CardHeading>
        </CardHeader>

        <CardBody>
          <CardFieldset>
            <CardInput placeholder="Username" type="text" required />
          </CardFieldset>

          <CardFieldset>
            <CardInput placeholder="E-mail" type="text" required />
          </CardFieldset>

          <CardFieldset>
            <CardInput placeholder="Password" type="password" required />
            <CardIcon className="fa fa-eye" eye small />
          </CardFieldset>

          <CardFieldset>
            <CardOptionsNote>Or sign up with</CardOptionsNote>

            <CardOptions>
              <CardOptionsItem>
                <CardIcon className="fab fa-google" big />
              </CardOptionsItem>

              <CardOptionsItem>
                <CardIcon className="fab fa-twitter" big />
              </CardOptionsItem>

              <CardOptionsItem>
                <CardIcon className="fab fa-facebook" big />
              </CardOptionsItem>
            </CardOptions>
          </CardFieldset>

          <CardFieldset>
            <CardButton type="button">Sign Up</CardButton>
          </CardFieldset>

          <CardFieldset>
            <CardLink>I already have an account</CardLink>
          </CardFieldset>
        </CardBody>
      </CardWrapper>
    </>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

Attempt at injecting stylesheet for CardWrapper:

```js
/*global chrome*/
/* src/content.js */

import React from 'react';
import { useContext, FrameContext } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Frame, { FrameContextConsumer } from 'react-frame-component';
import { StyleSheetManager } from 'styled-components';
import App from "./App";


export const StyledFrame = (props) => {
  const {
  CardWrapper,
  CardHeader,
  CardHeading,
  CardBody,
  CardFieldset,
  CardInput,
  CardIcon,
  CardOptionsNote,
  CardOptions,
  CardOptionsItem,
  CardButton,
  CardLink,
  } = props;

    class Main extends React.Component {
      render() {
          return (
            <Frame head={[<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href={chrome.runtime.getURL("/static/css/content.css")} ></link>]}>
                <InjectFrameStyles>
                    {props.CardWrapper}
                </InjectFrameStyles>
            </Frame>
          )
      }
    }
};

const InjectFrameStyles = (props) => {
  const { document } = useContext(FrameContext);
  return <StyleSheetManager target={document.head}>{props.CardWrapper}</StyleSheetManager>;
}

const app = document.createElement('div');
app.id = "my-extension-root";

document.body.appendChild(app);
ReactDOM.render(<Main />, app);

app.style.display = "none";

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
   function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
      if( request.message === "clicked_browser_action") {
        toggle();
      }
   }
);

function toggle(){
   if(app.style.display === "none"){
     app.style.display = "block";
   }else{
     app.style.display = "none";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem. I ended up creating a helper component called StyledFrame.

What happens is that your styled-components css is being rendered in the parent frame. You need to intercept those styles, and render them inside your iframe instead. Thats what StyleSheetManager is for.

You can use StyledFrame just like you would the Frame component.

```js
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import Frame, { FrameContext } from 'react-frame-component';
import { StyleSheetManager } from 'styled-components';

export const StyledFrame = (props) => {
  const { style, children, ...otherProps } = props;

  return (
    <Frame
      initialContent={
        '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><div class="frame-root"></div><div id="modal-root"></div></body></html>'
      }
      style={{ display: 'block', overflow: 'scroll', border: 0, ...style }}
      {...otherProps}
    >
      <InjectFrameStyles>{props.children}</InjectFrameStyles>
    </Frame>
  );
};

const InjectFrameStyles = (props) => {
  const { document } = useContext(FrameContext);
  return <StyleSheetManager target={document.head}>{props.children}</StyleSheetManager>;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this. In your code, when you're declaring the const {style, children, ...otherProps }, what would this be exactly? Does this mean I would need to take the styled.divs that I've created for each component, and have to declare it in my content.js file?

Comment: @LemonSquareCakes thats just prop destructuring. If you notice, I am spreading the style prop into style, and rendering children after InjectingFrameStyles. The rest are spread on Frame as otherProps. You can change the initialContent and style to meet your needs.