# Import SCSS files as string and store to variable and inject to iframe

Tags: reactjs, iframe, next.js, react-frame-component

How can I import the content of .scss file as a CSS string in Next.js?
I need something like this:

// scss file

```
.bg-red { 
  background-color: red;
}
```

Use the content as variable:

```
let styleString = 
.bg-red { 
  background-color: red;
}
```

And inject it to iframe (I'm using react-frame-component library)

```
<Frame head={
<style>{styleString}</style>
}>
</Frame>
```

I need something like this but for scss instead of styled-components:
[Styled components are not rendering in React Iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66556752/styled-components-are-not-rendering-in-react-iframe/66557426#66557426)

I think this might be what I'm looking for, but don't want to modify webpack config as much as possible.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-to-string